# A positive-edged D-Flip-Flop

Tags: digital-logic

I'm very confused in a positive edged D Flip-Flop.

The task specifically says that "create a A positively-triggered D-Flip-Flop".

This one is a positively triggered master and slave D-Flip-Flop which has a D latch and a SR latch.

[image]

[image]

Shoulnd't also this be a positively triggered D-Flip-Flop because when it's positive it outputs Q? Not sure if this is a gated D-latch.
[image]

And then there is a wikipedia one:
[image]

Which one do I use because they are all positively triggered D Flip-Flops?

Comment: What is the CT circuit shown in the third implementation? Is it to provide a positive pulse of a fixed width at the rising edge of the CLK?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implementation is actually the same as the second one with the exception that the first one appears to be a -ve edge triggered flipflop whereas the second is +ve edge triggered. The last one seems better to me as it has a lower gate count.

The third implementation is basically a gated D-latch with the latch enable being generated by a special CT circuit. I have not seen this topology being used probably because it needs this extra CT circuit.

Comment: So is this a positive edged D flip flop?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqYH.png

Comment: Yes it is assuming that Q of the first latch is connected to S of the second. Do you have any reason in mind why you think it may not be? Or you just are looking for confirmation?

Comment: I'm just looking for confirmation